# ASP.NET Invoking Outlook w/ attached file

Tags: c#

How can I invoke Outlook window on server-side through a click button with an attached file located on the root web folder?

Comment: That sounds like an bad idea.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: BAAAAAAD idea.  Why do you want to do this?  Do you just want to send an email with an attachment?  There are MUCH better ways, less likely to crash your server.

Comment: I assume he wants to show a compose window on the client.

Comment: Yes on command just need outlook to come up with a (text) file pre-attached. I read somewhere that this can not be performed on the client machine but rather on the server. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to allow the user to upload an email and then send it, you'd be better off following this tutorial:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150716/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080206-1.aspx

Automating a client app server-side is a bad idea.  What if Outlook prompts the user to do something?  Who will be there to answer the prompts?

Also, any version of Outlook at or higher than the 2003 version WILL prompt if you try to automate sending emails, so this isn't even feasible unless you have an old version of Outlook on the server.